# Android Custom Spinner problems

Tags: android, spinner, android-custom-view

In my application, I am working with Custom Spinner.

For this purpose, I followed a tutorial [link](http://stephenpengilley.blogspot.in/2013/01/android-custom-spinner-tutorial.html)
While following this tutorial, I am facing a little problem where, whenever user selects a particular item from Spinner Drop-down, title of the spinner disappears and in that place the name of the selected item is displayed, as shown in the following image.

But, here what I want is that, there should be a fixed title that must appear on spinner.
And another problem is that when i did a selection from drop-down , previous selected item gets appear in the place of selected item in drop-down.
As shown in figure.

activity_main.xml

```
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <Spinner
          android:id="@+id/customspinner"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
          android:background="@drawable/btn_dropdown" 
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
```

spinner_row.xml

```
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
    >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/spinnerText"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Spinner Items" />
```

and this is my Adapter Code.

Spinner spi.setAdapter(new MyCustomSpinner());

public class MyCustomSpinner extends BaseAdapter
    {

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View myCustomView=convertView;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            myCustomView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, null);

            TextView tv=(TextView)myCustomView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText);
            tv.setText(myList.get(position));
        }
        return myCustomView;
    }

}
```

[image]  [image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is shown in the example- "Planet" is a textview above the spinner in a layout xml, no need to associate title with the spinner-code or its values then

Comment: if that is what you are asking (?) , else paste a screenshot with expected output and your current xml(s)